# Bootstrap Carousel .hidden-sm causes blank space

Tags: html, css

I'm using bootstrap carousel for image slideshow. I'm trying to hide certain images when viewed on an ipad. However, when I use the .hidden-sm, it hides the image, but causes a white blank space. How can I just hide the image, with no blank space? I've tried using an id then doing display:none for that id tag, but it doesnt work as well.

Also using hidden-sm, overwrites the "active" and it becomes the first image that is seen onload of the carousel.

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="item active">
                <img src="./img/image_00.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>

            <div class="item hidden-sm">
                <img src="./img/image_01.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/image_02.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/image_03.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden-sm{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Instead of applying the hidden style to the image itself, try putting it on the `<li>`.  You're not showing all of your code here though.

Comment: @Marc I'm showing all my code, I'm using bootstrap, hence I think there's no <li> needed in my html

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that even though the item is hidden, it still is part of the DOM so the carousel will still show the empty image.  There are ways to remove it from the DOM using JavaScript but if you're looking for a CSS-only answer the best way is to have 2 separate carousels.  One that is shown on tablet, one that is shown on every other screen size.

Notice the first carousel would be only shown on all screens except tablets, so it has images 0, 1, 2, 3.  The second carousel is shown ONLY on tablets and it has images 0, 2, 3.  Image 1 is completely gone so it will not be shown at all

```
<div class="carousel-inner hidden-sm">

            <div class="item active">
                <img src="./img/image_00.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/image_01.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/image_02.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/image_03.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
</div>

<div class="carousel-inner visible-sm">

            <div class="item active">
                <img src="./img/image_00.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/image_02.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="./img/image_03.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much. if having it as such, will it cause a slower loading? would it be more efficient to use js? Or it doesnt make a difference. Sorry, still pretty new to this, so trying to understand what is the most effective way to do this. Thanks again

Comment: I've tried and tested the code. However it causes a blank page, when i start going to and fro between images. Any idea why that happens.